# Oozie workflow succeeds when map-reduce task throws exceptions - I want it to fail

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

I have an Oozie workflow that runs a map-reduce task like this:

```
<action name="generate">
    <map-reduce>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        ...
            <property>
                <name>mapred.mapper.class</name>
                <value>com.tendril.pr.report.generate.ReportGenerationMapper</value>
            </property>
```

My mapper class is ReportGenerationMapper which implements the interface  Mapper interface. This class is instantiated and the map() method is called by the hadoop system just fine. During the course of the method call though a runtime exception occurs and appears in the log like this:

Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, hdfs-default.xml, hdfs-site.xml, /data/1/mapred/local/tasktracker/taskTracker/root/jobcache/job_201402032014_4231/job.xml
com.tendril.pr.core.domain.TendrilException: Could not retrieve property null
...

This is all fine, but the workflow succeeds and I want it to fail. I can't seem to make it fail. I searched without any luck on how to fail the task that is running this mapper. My oozie jobs succeeds and gives no indication of a failure without diving into this task and looking at the logs. I want the failure to be obvious by having the task and whole workflow fail. Any advice on how to make this happen?

Comment: Do you have `<error to ="kill"/>` for this action?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to capture the exit code within the driver class and throw exception manually from there.